# NPE with initialized variable

Tags: java, swing

Can someone explain to me why I am getting a NullPointerException in the getRowCount() method? The variable is initialized with an empty ArrayList...

```
public class BeschriftungssetTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4980235976337188354L;

    private List<BeschriftungssetBean> data = new ArrayList<>();


    public void setData(List<BeschriftungssetBean> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        return data.get(row).getBezeichnung();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return "Bezeichnung";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BeschriftungssetTableModel beschriftungssetTableModel = new BeschriftungssetTableModel();
        beschriftungssetTableModel.getRowCount();
    }
}



public class BeschriftungssetBean {
    private String objId;
    private String bezeichnung;

    public String getBezeichnung() {
        return bezeichnung;
    }

    public void setBezeichnung(String bezeichnung) {
        this.bezeichnung = bezeichnung;
    }

    public String getObjId() {
        return objId;
    }

    public void setObjId(String objId) {
        this.objId = objId;
    }
}
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ch.aaa.xxx.yyy.gruppen.plugin.anzeige.beschriftungseinstellungen.BeschriftungssetTableModel.getRowCount(BeschriftungssetTableModel.java:36)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setDataVector(DefaultTableModel.java:224)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.<init>(DefaultTableModel.java:124)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.<init>(DefaultTableModel.java:106)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.<init>(DefaultTableModel.java:86)
at ch.aaa.xxx.yyy.gruppen.plugin.anzeige.beschriftungseinstellungen.BeschriftungssetTableModel.<init>(BeschriftungssetTableModel.java:18)
at ch.aaa.xxx.yyy.gruppen.plugin.anzeige.beschriftungseinstellungen.BeschriftungssetTableModel.main(BeschriftungssetTableModel.java:50)
```

Comment: Could you add the stack trace for the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: I already debugged the method and it says that "data" in "getRowCount" is null which then causes the exception.

Comment: OK, I see that is weird... You haven't initialized it with `null` (but with raw type `ArrayList<>`)...

Comment: In the main method you can see that nothing else is done

Comment: If your plan is to replace everything DefaultTableModel does by your own methods, and to use your own list rather than the data that DefaultTableModel uses, implement AbstractTableModel instead of extending DefaultTableModel.

Comment: Unrelated: consider not mixing languages in your code. And as BeschriftungsMengeBohne sounds really bad, I would rather go all English `InscriptionSetBean` for example.

Comment: I would definately go with @JBNizet 's advice and extend AbstractTableModel

Comment: @GhostCat this clearly depends on the context. Although I've preached the same advice in the past, some domains are better expressed in the native language of the participants, even if it leads to an ugly english-foreign mix.

Comment: After a long time, I'm seeing the first question complaining `NullPointerException`, which was not closed. ;)

Comment: @spi: And it makes your code MUCH harder to read when you're open-sourcing parts of it, accepting a foreigner into your team, or asking questions about it on stackoverflow. Production code should be English-only, period.

Comment: @HardikModha When the answer can be somewhat useful to somebody else (because it depends on some technology/library/etc) and not just the OP.

Comment: @user202729 That was a sarcastic comment. It was indeed a good question and I also learned something new today! :)

Comment: @GuntramBlohm well it's complicated enough to know all the special terms that exist in german... let alone finding the correct translation... there would be absolutely no benefits for our projects since speaking german is a requirement

Comment: @GuntramBlohm there is hardly anything true all the time. When there is no chance the code will be outsourced someday (eg. legal reasons) and your business is very specifiy to a region/country/language, you will only get brain overload and misunderstanding not using your native language. But I agree, the general rule of thumb should be all-english.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The constructor of `DefaultTableModel` calls `getRowCount` before the subclass had a chance to initialize its content, thus leading to NPE with your implem. This is a bad design of the base class, as calling overridable methods from within a constructor is considered a bad practice, but hey, Swing API has quite a few of these :)

Cf. [What's wrong with overridable method calls in constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors)

Comment: *"...as calling overridable methods from within a constructor is considered a bad practice..."* For precisely this reason. :-)

Answer (score 13):

Do not extend `DefaultTableModel`, extend `AbstractTableModel` instead.

`DefaultTableModel` uses a Vector to maintain the data and does not expect you having your own data in a subclass. As @spi wrote, it is calling `getRowCount` which was overriden to return the size of `data` that is not yet initialized.

The `AbstractTableModel` is easy to extend (`DefaultTableModel` also does), just these 3 methods need to be implemented (already done in questions code):

```
public int getRowCount();
public int getColumnCount();
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column);
```

Others methods can be overridden to adjust its behavior like `isCellEditable` or `getColumnClass`. If the data is changed the appropriate `fireXXX` method should be called so the registered listeners are invoked (e.g. `JTable` using that model).

An alternative is to implement `TableModel`, but `AbstractTableModel` takes care of some *standard* (nasty?) functionality like maintaining the listeners.

<sup>(**bad** alternative, just check for `null`, but this probably will mess up with the `DefaultTableModel` code - do not do this)</sup>